# How can I access Html or txt file in Android Studio and convert it to a String?

Tags: android, html

I'm an Android beginner making an app that downloads HTML content from a webpage in the form of a single string and then displays some of that content in a user-friendly format. It takes a while for that content to download (see [Android app taking forever to download web content (WaitForGcToComplete blocked for xx.xxxms for cause HeapTrim?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110814/android-app-taking-forever-to-download-web-content-waitforgctocomplete-blocked)), so while I'm developing it, I'd like to save that single string within the app so I can run and test the app without re-downloading the content each time.

I tried creating a raw folder within the res directory and copying and pasting the HTML file into there, but after doing that, I couldn't figure out how to access the HTML file and convert it to a string. I found lots of answers suggesting ways to convert it to a string, but none that helped me figure out how to access the file itself in a way that would help me achieve my goal. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bhargav's way of accessing the html file (line 1 below) was accurate. However, the rest of the code was way too slow. Here's the solution I used:

`InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.html_file);`

`StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();`

`InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            try {
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    stringBuilder.append(current);
                    data = reader.read();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            webContent = stringBuilder.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
     InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.html_file);

     try {
         int size = is.available();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
         is.read(buffer);
         is.close();
         String str = new String(buffer);
      } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I run this code, the app doesn't get past the "new String" line. I tried adding a second parameter to the constructor based on some research ("UTF-8"), but the app still didn't get past that line of code. Is that line supposed to take several minutes to run? If not, do you have any ideas as to why the app can't get past it? By the way, in case it's relevant, I'm running this code inside an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the HTML file by the following code:

```
int ch;
    StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();


        try {
            FileInputStream fis =  openFileInput("htmlFile.html");
            try {
                while ((ch=fis.read())!=-1)
                    str.append((char)ch);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    //convert to string
    String s=str.toString();
```

Comment: When using this method, I'm unfortunately getting a java.io.FileNotFoundException: </data/data/PACKGENAME/files/HTMLNAME.html: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)>. Recall that the file is in the app/res/raw folder. Do you know how I can direct the app to access the file? By the way, in case it's relevant, I'm running this code inside an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is temporary, perhaps just putting it into a string at the bottom of the file is sufficient?

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //use myHtmlCode here
  }

  private static String myHtmlCode = "lots of html";
}
```

On the other hand, with a longer-term view, you want to be able to run tests on your app.  If your app has to hit the network to run those tests, it's going to be slower and you won't be sure whether errors are caused by the network connect/what the server is returning or by your own code.

With that in mind, it's nice to be able to have a setting that allows you to use mocked data (as from a file, like you mentioned).  One approach to this would be using [product flavor](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html), where you could have different versions of your app--one that gets the html from a server, and another that gets the html from a file.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I tried something similar to this method (putting the encoded string into the strings.xml file and trying to create a string in my app code from that), but unfortunately it didn't work (and was slow). Your point about the longer-term view makes a lot of sense, though, which is why I'm really hoping someone might be able to help me out with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110814/android-app-taking-forever-to-download-web-content-as-string-waitforgctocomplet)!